# How to add Bearer token Authorization in Retrofit Flutter

Tags: flutter, retrofit

How to add Bearer token Authorization in Retrofit Flutter.

Here is Retrofit Service

```
@RestApi(baseUrl: "https://***.****.xyz/api/")
abstract class ApiService{

  factory ApiService(Dio dio) => _ApiService(dio);

  @POST("auth/login")
  Future<AuthModel> login(@Body() Map<String,dynamic> map);

  @POST("auth/singup")
  Future<AuthModel> singup(@Body() Map<String,dynamic> map);

  @GET('{id}')
  Future<UserModel> getUser( @Path() String id);

}
```

And Then Create Dio and add into GetIt and insert into ApiService.

```
var getIt = GetIt.I;
void locator(){

  Dio dio = Dio();
  

  getIt.registerLazySingleton(() => dio);

   ApiService apiService = ApiService(getIt.call());
  getIt.registerLazySingleton(() => apiService);

  Repository repository = Repository(getIt.call());
  getIt.registerLazySingleton(() => repository);

  LoginCubit loginCubit = LoginCubit(getIt.call());
  getIt.registerLazySingleton(() => loginCubit);
 
  GetProfileCubit getProfileCubit = GetProfileCubit(getIt.call());
  getIt.registerLazySingleton(() => getProfileCubit);

}
```

and Create Repository

```
class Repository{
  final ApiService _apiService;
  Repository(this._apiService);

  Future<AuthModel> logIn(Map<String,dynamic> map) => _apiService.login(map);
  Future<AuthModel> singUp(Map<String,dynamic> map) => _apiService.singup(map);
  Future<UserModel> getUser(String id) => _apiService.getUser(id);

}
```

Please answer my question sir. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the optimal way but this should work fine.

Change your `ApiService` class as follows:

```
@RestApi(baseUrl: "https://***.****.xyz/api/")
abstract class ApiService{

   .... same code ....

  @GET('{id}')
  Future<UserModel> getUser( 
     @Header('Authorization') String token,
     @Path() String id
       );

 .... same code ....
}
```

Also change your `Repository` class:

```
class Repository{
  .... same code ...
  //// Pass token as a parameter
  ///// Add Bearer before your token
 
  Future<UserModel> getUser(String token, String id) => 
      _apiService.getUser('Bearer $token',id);

}
```

**Happy Coding TT**

Comment: Thanks sir, it work well. By the way can I add the token to every ApiCall in once?

Answer (score 3):

Retrofit uses [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) so you can implement a Dio interceptor.

Here is an example of how to create an interceptor.

```
class TokenInterceptor extends Interceptor {

  @override
  Future onRequest(
    RequestOptions options,
    RequestInterceptorHandler handler,
  ) async {
    // Here you can put the token, either from preference, sqlite, etc.
    // Here is an example with Preferences
    final someToken? = prefs.getString('token');
    // After you choose your token, you assign it to the request.
    options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ${someToken}';
    super.onRequest(options, handler);
  }

  @override
  void onResponse(Response response, ResponseInterceptorHandler handler) {
    // Do something with response data
    super.onResponse(response, handler);
  }

  @override
  Future onError(
    DioError err,
    ErrorInterceptorHandler handler,
  ) async {
    // If the error is 401 Unauthorized, log out the user
    if (err.response?.statusCode == 401) {
      _repository.logOut();
      _appDatabase.userDao.deleteAllUsers();
    }
    super.onError(err, handler);
  }
}
```

Then you must add the interceptor to Dio

```
var getIt = GetIt.I;
void locator(){

  Dio dio = Dio();
  dio.interceptors.add(TokenInterceptor()); // Add this code

  getIt.registerLazySingleton(() => dio);

   ApiService apiService = ApiService(getIt.call());
  getIt.registerLazySingleton(() => apiService);

  Repository repository = Repository(getIt.call());
  getIt.registerLazySingleton(() => repository);

  LoginCubit loginCubit = LoginCubit(getIt.call());
  getIt.registerLazySingleton(() => loginCubit);
 
  GetProfileCubit getProfileCubit = GetProfileCubit(getIt.call());
  getIt.registerLazySingleton(() => getProfileCubit);

}
```

[Linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/retrofit-flutter-like-pro-idan-ayalon/) there is a good post with more configurations that may be interesting.